# Profiling tools for Linux and performance monitoring counters for ARM

Tags: linux, arm, profiling, intel, ds-5

The question is mainly regarding the `profiling tools` available for `ARM` processors - Specifically `ARM v7` ; I'm using a `Linux`

I played around with Intel and AMD processors and I know that they have various profiling tools like `Perf`, `perfmon` and `valgrind` which will allow me to monitor various counters like `retired instructions, cache misses, floating point unit, integral units, etc.`

However, I don't know if `ARM` also supports these kind of profiling tools. Do you know any tools that can be used on ARM processors.

I searched through the ARM [reference manual](http://www.scribd.com/doc/148184832/ARMv7-M-ARM) but I failed to find the performance counters list. For example, in `Intel` processors you can find them in the `ref. manual` and `OProfile` webpage. Is there a manual or a webpage which lists the list of `performance monitoring counters` for `ARM`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ARMv7-A profile](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html), which is targeted for hosting a rich OS has similar performance counters like `Intel` . It looks like you have looked into `v7-M profile` which is targeted for micro-controller environments. Most of the recent ARM cores that runs Linux, like [Cortex-A9](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a9.php) are from this profile.

[Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) already supports performance counters on `ARM` architecture, same with `oprofile`.

ARM company also provides a eye-candy eclipse based environment called [DS-5 Streamline](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/optimize/) as well with lots of extra features to help you analyze performance issues.

Comment: You do need more recent Linux versions to get this support.

Comment: @artlessnoise that goes with everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind is supported on ARM. See [here](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But There was some more detailed information below and therefore, I ticked it as correct.

Comment: No explanation required. I do not do this for votes. Thanks though :)

Comment: I did not say that. Technical stuff is always fun - that's why most of us play at work!

Comment: But, from the [documentation for valgrind's profiler callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html): _"Callgrind's ability to detect function calls and returns depends on the instruction set of the platform it is run on. It works best on x86 and amd64, and unfortunately currently does not work so well on PowerPC, ARM, Thumb or MIPS code. This is because there are no explicit call or return instructions in these instruction sets, so Callgrind has to rely on heuristics to detect calls and returns."_

Comment: No it doesn't, it crashes with "Unrecognised instruction"